# Running Total Sum

Tags: crystal-reports

im having a real headhache with this. 
Im trying to get a Running Total to make a sum of certain items that correspond to a condition. I dont know how to procede now

```
while {Movimientos.IVA} = 0 do Sum ({Movimientos.Importe}, {Movimientos.RFC})
```

it really makes the sum but it takes wrong values, because i have 2 items that correspond to Movimientos.IVA = 0 and it doesnt sum them. It sums the values that are different to 0. By the other hand this is my configuration for Running Total:

on Evaulate i have use formula
on Reset i have on group change: and my group that is Movimientos.RFC what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a standard Crystal Running Total then you can use an Evaluate formula to only match certain fields within the summary group.  As described [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.businessobjects.integration.eclipse.doc.crdesigner/reportdesigner/crtskcreatingconditionalrunningtotals.htm), you would:

1. Create your running total
2. Add a formula to evaluate under Running Total Condition, matching the condition you use above in your while loop: `{Movimientos.IVA} = 0`
3. Position the running total in your report layout.

Comment: i have done that with no luck, i have 2 running total in the footer of the group, the one that evaluates >0 is done right, but this one no.

Comment: doing it the way you told me the running total is just empty. I have done this too with no luck neither, this is done on a formula field and the field appears me in 0.00 [code] if {Movimientos.IVA} = 0 then 
sum ({Movimientos.Importe})[/code]

Comment: What do you mean when you say "this is done on a formula field"?